# Why is the destructor called upon construction of an object in std::vector::push_back(T object) method?

Tags: c++, vector, destructor, stdvector

I have this line here:

```
someSTLVector.push_back(SomeClass(...));
```

I was hoping what `SomeClass` would be constructed and moved to the back of the vector, without any copies. However, the destructor got called here. I tried amending this with an `std::move`:

```
someSTLVector.push_back(std::move(SomeClass(...)));
```

but the result didn't change.

I also tried defining the following in the `SomeClass`:

```
SomeClass(SomeClass&&) = default;
SomeClass& operator= (SomeClass&&) = default;
SomeClass(const SomeClass&) = delete;
SomeClass& operator= (const SomeClass&) = delete;
```

That didn't help either, the destructor was still called. Note that the `SomeClass` contains a reference as a member

It's apparent that `SomeClass` gets constructed and then copied into the vector. I want't to avoid that and have it be constructed as a part of the vector (or at least moved to the vector, avoiding any copying). `SomeClass` manages a resources which gets released in the destructor. If the destructor is called when copying the object, the resource is released and the object becomes invalid, pointing to a resource that no longer exists.

How can I instantiate a class where the resulting object will be placed to the back of the vector, but not copied (and thus destroyed) in the process?

Comment: This is the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You don't have any problem with `std::vector`. Your problem is that your defaulted move constructor doesn't do the correct thing. You must either delete it or define it to do the right thing.

Comment: True, but I did include enough information for people to understand what actually needs to be done.

Comment: The issue is that answering the explicitly stated question will only resolve a symptom of the actual described problem. Using `emplace_back` will avoid this particular move/copy, but the class is still broken and the vector will sporadically fail if the move constructor is not defined with correct semantics. So answers will need to consider answering the explicit question as well as the (unrelated) underlying problem. It would be better to ask directly about the underlying problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was hoping what SomeClass would be constructed and moved to the back of the vector, without any copies.

That is what does happen.

> However, the destructor got called here.

Indeed. That would be the temporary object that you passed to the move constructor:

> ```
> someSTLVector.push_back(SomeClass(...));
>                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

That there is syntax for initialisation of a temporary object.

> It's apparent that SomeClass gets constructed and then copied into the vector.

Well, *moved* to be exact. Although moving is a form of copying.

> I want't to avoid that and have it be constructed as a part of the vector (or at least moved to the vector, avoiding any copying).

You've already managed to avoid the copying. To avoid the move, you can use the `emplace_back` member function instead of `push_back`:

```
someSTLVector.emplace_back(...);
```

This forwards the arguments directly to the constructor of the element.

---

> If the destructor is called when copying the object, the resource is released and the object becomes invalid, pointing to a resource that no longer exists.

If your destructor releases some resources, then the defaulted move constructor / assignment are probably not doing what you would want them to do. See rule of five / three.

Answer (score 2):

An object that is moved is still destructed. So your `SomeClass` is probably moved into the vector (you could add a `std::cout <<` message in your move constructor to verify) but it is then also destructed.

You can call `std::vector::emplace_back` to have the item constructed right into the vector. However, that still doesn't guarantee your object won't be moved (e.g. if the vector needs to grow it can allocate more space and then move all the objects to the new storage and then destroy them in their original location).

If you have some resource you're releasing in the destructor you need to ensure you don't do that release if the object was moved. Typically move constructors "empty" out the moved-from object (e.g. given `SomeClass(SomeClass&& other)` in that method you'd modify `other` to "empty it"). Then your destructor can see if it's "empty" (has been moved from) and not release whatever resources you're holding.